# how to prepend each letter with a symbol using Regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string time format like this: `d-m-Y H:i`. I want to format it like this: `%d-%m-%Y %H:%i`.

How do I prepend each letter with `%` using regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic using `String#gsub`:

```
str = "d-m-Y H:i"
str.gsub(/[a-z]/i, '%\0')
# => "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i"
```

In the replacement string `'%\0'`, `\0` represents the entire match, which in this case is the matched letter, so this says, "Replace each letter with a `%` followed by the letter."

Comment: I was not aware of `\0`. Good to know. I poked around the docs looking for it, but came up empty. Do you know where it's documented? (I did find references to it elsewhere, [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) for one.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Huh. It doesn't seem to be documented. I'm not sure how I found out about it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sorted 'd-m-Y H:i'.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]+/) { |sym| "%#{sym}" }
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
'd-m-Y H:i'.gsub(/(?=[a-z])/i, '%')
  #=> "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i"
```

This reads, "replace every empty string followed by a lowercase or uppercase letter with the character '%'". `(?=[a-z])` is a positive lookahead.